# Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 app which works fine on my local machine but doesn't work on the application server and throws the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**Web config:**

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

When I change the version of System.Web.Mvc to exect version i.e. **4.0.40804.0** I got almost the similar error:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.40804.0" newVersion="4.0.40804.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

> LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file: D:\mywebapp\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/f56977f7/c98ce4c8/System.Web.Mvc.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/root/f56977f7/c98ce4c8/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/RHDHV_Websites/Graafgebiedinformatie/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\mywebapp\web.config LOG:
>   Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.1
>   redirected to 4.0.40804.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=4.0.40804.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/f56977f7/c98ce4c8/System.Web.Mvc.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/root/f56977f7/c98ce4c8/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/RHDHV_Websites/Graafgebiedinformatie/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision
>   Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.

Any help or tip is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to use some kind of elimination process:

**Restore your binding redirects**

1. Make sure that you have the same web config on both environments (local and remote)
2. Clean+Build your project. Got to the bin environment, get all the dlls and paste them in the deployment folder. Check that the System.Web.Mvc.dll is among these.
3. Make sure that the mvc dll is referenced in the References of your MVC project.

Longshot. Change the binding redirect to

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
```

You can also try to install the same .net verstion on the remote server as your machine has, though if all is deoployed well it should not matter.

The second log makes sense. It just doesn't find any dlls at all to load, so it's not a missmatch.

Comment: I did change the version as suggested and worked as intended. Many thanks

Comment: Ok, just so you understand why. I noticed that it was loaded in the second log which most probably means that 4.0.0.0 is not on the machine so the redirect fails :). Glad I could help.